# Templated Method - É possivel implementar com composição ao invés de herança?

Tags: java, design-pattern

Para criar uma *Thread* podemos tanto estender a classe *Thread* e sobrescrever o método `run()`, como ter uma classe que implementa a interface *Runnable*, implementar o método `run()` e passar a referencia de um objeto dessa classe que criamos como argumento para o construtor da *Thread*.

Observando o código do método `start()` vi que faz uma chamada ao método `run()` que poderia ser interpretado, ao meu ver, como um etapa para a execução do método `start()` da *Thread*.

Seria possível aplicar o *template method* usando composição?

A classe *Thread* do pacote `java.lang` poderia ser visto como um bom exemplo deste padrão usando composição?

Dado a definição do [pattern](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/pat/template.htm):

> Define o esqueleto de um algoritmo numa operação, deixando que subclasses completem algumas das etapas.

Seria possível afirmar o que foi exposto acima?

Answer (score 1):

Sim é possível,e ela tem vantagens para implementar no template method.

As vantagens são :

> 1º É implementada simplesmente por encaminhar todas as chamadas para um campo de objeto.
>
> 2º Não tem nenhuma dependência de detalhes da implementação.
>
> 3º É mais flexível,uma vez que é definida dinamicamente em tempo de execução,e não estaticamente em tempo de compilação.
>
> 4º Fácil de se ler.
>
> 5º Fácil de se testar(não há classes abstratas e todas dependências são declaradas diretamente).

Mas ao mesmo tempo em que há vantagens,há também desvantagens,como :

> 1º Dependências devem ser gerenciadas diretamente por getters ou no construtor
>
> 2º É muito menos intuitivo no começo,e se você está acostumado de outra forma,será mais complicado de se acostumar com o código.
>
> 3º É pouco detalhado no que diz respeito à utilização de herança

E uma das regras da orientação de objetos é :

> "Favorecer a composição de objetos sobre heranças de classes.Pois uma vez que se utiliza heranças de classes fica o uso até que excessivo por causa de reutilização de códigos.Se você usar composição de objetos,irá aplicar uma vez ou outra nos padrões do design"

Para saber mais sobre,dê uma olhada aqui :

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=72

https://fillumina.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/comparison-between-composition-and-template-pattern/

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=164